# How to insert a variable in Varnish regex

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I have a variable I'd like to include in Varnish regex match, but having trouble finding the correct syntax, example below.  Appreciate any tips.

if (req.url !~ "slreturn=(req.http.yearMonthDay)") {...

Answer (score 0):

@Kari I see that you're using a mixture of double quotes & single quotes to interpolate the `req.http.YearMonthDay` header into the regex.

Please use double quotes only as illustrated below:

```
if (req.url ~ "slreturn=" && req.url ~ "[?:"+req.http.yearMonthDay+"]" ) {
  std.log("------> YOU MATCHED. GO FORTH AND DO STUFF ");
}
```

If that still doesn't work for you, please paste the error that the Varnish compiler returns when starting Varnish.

Comment: Hmmm that should work, I did:

    if (req.url ~ "slreturn=" && req.url ~ "[?:"+req.http.yearMonthDay+"]" )

but compiler complains - prolly why was messing with single quotes.
    
    Message from VCC-compiler:
    Regexp compilation error:
    
    missing terminating ] for character class

Comment: That's a regex error, not a pure VCL syntax error. Try to print the parsed regex as a string and debug it on a site like https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

I changed my thinking, using std.strstr made a huge difference.

```
if (std.strstr(req.url, req.http.yearMonthDay)) {
  // Do something based on the match
  std.log("------> YOU MATCHED TO TODAY. WHAT DO YOU WANT TO DO NOW? ");
}
```